# When I'm switching a tab, it comes back to the initial tab. How can I fix it?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Here the tabs part of code:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
       <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Main</a>
       <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="/questions" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Questions</a>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Href attribute also somehow doesn't work

Comment: Did you include JS resources?

Comment: Please include them and see if it works or not.

Comment: no, not working(

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#js):

> Components requiring JavaScript:
>
> - Alerts for dismissing
> - Buttons for toggling states and checkbox/radio functionality
> - Carousel for all slide behaviors, controls, and indicators
> - Collapse for toggling visibility of content
> - Dropdowns for displaying and positioning (also requires [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org))
> - Modals for displaying, positioning, and scroll behavior
> - Navbar for extending our Collapse plugin to implement responsive behavior
> - Tooltips and popovers for displaying and positioning (also requires [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org))
> - Scrollspy for scroll behavior and navigation updates

You should also include JS files ([jQuery](https://jquery.com), [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org), [BootstrapJS](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js)) to make some components work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Main</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#questions" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Questions</a>
    </div>
</div>
```